# How do I stop each function when I append with same class

Tags: jquery, html, each

> HTML

```
<button id="add_div"> show more </button>
```

> JQUERY

**The more I add the class "show_div_value" whenever I click the show value the more the alert shows**

```
var inc_numbers;

$("#add_div").click(function() { 
     inc_numbers += 1;

     $('parent_div').append('<button id="'+ inc_numbers +'" class="
     show_div_value" value="inc_numbers"></button><button class="
     show_button" id="'+ inc_numbers +'"> show value </button>'); 

     //DISPLAYS 2 buttons with the same ID 

});

$(".show_button").click(function() {
     var get_btn_id = $(this).attr('id');

     $(".show_div_value").each(function() {
          var get_div_id = $(this).attr('id');

          if(get_btn_id == get_div_id) {
              alert($(this).val());
              return false; //I put this here but it doesn't seem to work out
          }
     });    
});
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: when I append 1 div and click it's show button, it alerts once. When I append another div which is the 2nd div and click the 2nd div's show button it alerts also once. But when I click the show button value of div 1 again, it alerts twice. And so on. What I want is whenever I append div's and click it's show button, I want to alert only once per button

Comment: What's the function called when you click the `#add_div` button, and why you get alert?

Comment: I updated the code of the click function. It is supposed to be add_div. I would rather simplify the code which has the same problem than posting the complexity of the real codes I'm currently doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your code as follows:

```js
var inc_numbers = 0;

$('#add_div').click(function() { 
   inc_numbers += 1;

   $('#parent_div').append( // Not $('parent_id').append()!
     '<button data-id="' + inc_numbers + '" class="show_div_value" value="' + inc_numbers + '" style="display: none;"></button>' +
     '<button class="show_button" id="' + inc_numbers + '"> show value </button>'
   );
   // Same id to two elements is invalid in HTML, so I use data- attributes.
   // This will do the jQuery code very simple,
   // beacuse I just need to select the .show_div_value with data-id equals to the id of the clicked button
});

$('#parent_div').on('click', '.show_button', function() {
   // Don't attach the listener directly to the button, because the button doesn't exist when you atatch the listener.
   // Because of this, you should use delegated event. See https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

   var div = $('.show_div_value[data-id=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']');
   console.log(div.val());  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add_div"> show more </button>
<div id="parent_div"></div>
```

Comment: "var div = $('.show_div_value[data-id=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']');"... how do I distinguish 1 ".show_div_value" that has an attribute name. Is it "var div = $('.show_div_value[data-id=' + $(this).attr('id') + '.attr('name')]');"?

Comment: What you mean? The CSS selector `[<attribute>="<value>"]` means: select all elements that their `<attribute>` equals to `<value>` (the parentheses are optional if there is no spaces).